# Bootstrap failed: 134: Service cannot load in requested session (macOs Ventura 13.0)

Tags: macos, macos-ventura, mutagen, launchctl

Trying to run this command

```
sudo launchctl bootstrap user/501 ~/Library/LaunchAgents/io.mutagen.mutagen.plist
```

and getting this error

```
/Users/simanta/Library/LaunchAgents/io.mutagen.mutagen.plist: Service cannot load in requested session
Bootstrap failed: 134: Service cannot load in requested session
```

The `io.mutagen.mutagen.plist` file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>io.mutagen.mutagen</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/mutagen</string>
        <string>daemon</string>
        <string>run</string>
    </array>
    <key>LimitLoadToSessionType</key>
    <string>Aqua</string>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I have read multiple blog posts but got no solution

Comment: I installed `launch-control` and found out that the mutagen file was not available in the file path `/usr/local/bin/`, I had to copy it manually, got the real path from `brew list mutagen`

Answer (score 0):

Update: Solved it by using symlink and pointing the directory where mutagen is installed, apparently in M1 chip the mutagen is installed in different directory